# Canon TS31775 Printer not printing in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, printing, scanner, canon

Canon TS31775 Printer not printing in ubuntu 20.04. The printer is detected as CUPS-BRF-PRINTER-2 but when given command for printing the document nothing happens. The printer supports scanning as well as printing but though scanning part is also not detected. Please help with any drivers that can be installed to proper functioning of the printer.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do mean Canon TS3177S?  Here is a modern technique supported by Ubuntu:https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSQuickPrintQueues

Answer (score 0):

Try this in terminal

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint
```

then add printer.